# How to start search manually from a command or mapping, after remapping /?

Tags: neovim, search

After remapping `/` to something other than search, how can I open the builtin search interface?

Normally in Vim, when you press `/`, a `/` appears in the bottom-left (where the command line also would be), and you can type the search pattern there, before pressing enter to submit the search.

If `/` has been remapped so that it no longer does this, how can I programmatically open this same interface that `/` normally would?

Comment: Maybe could you tell us what you want to achieve. Do you want to have access to search in normal mode? Do you want to access search in mappings?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt I rebound `/` to `:echo hi`, now how can I actually open the search interface?

Comment: Then the solution I proposed could help you? Did it?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt It doesn't open the search line, just submits a search itself. I've added a little to my question, I hope that makes it clearer what I mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Remapping

I would use another mapping with `nnoremap`

```
nnoremap , /
```

To search `foo` you could then do: `,foo`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

### Vimscript

You could use feedkeys with mappings turned off:

```
call feedkeys('/', 'n')
```

### normal!

You could use the `:normal!` command:

To search `foo` you could do `:normal! /foo`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

### Search History

You could also use the search history: `q/`

To search `foo` you could do `q/ifoo`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

### Final remark:

In the `:normal` mode you can use the `:normal!` version.

```
:normal! /foo^M
```

Comment: Oh you're right, I hadn't read this properly earlier, sorry. `nnoremap` works but `norm!` does not. Would you know how to open search from the command line? For some reason `:norm! /` does not work.

Comment: Do you know why `:nmap / <NOP>` then `:norm! /` does not open search?

Comment: My understanding of the `:normal` command is that after the argument an additional `<Esc>` character is appended. This make that you can use it to search but not to open the search. `:norm! /` is conceptually equivalent to `:call feedkeys("/\<Esc>", 'n')` although in my test it is not since  `:call feedkeys("/\<Esc>", 'n')`  seems to be the same as  `:call feedkeys("/\<CR>", 'n')`  for some reason that I ignore.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the solutions already covered by Vivian, you could also use <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd>`/`. Hitting <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> will also suppress mappings on the following key(s). See `:help c_CTRL-V` for details.

It should be noticed that pressing <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> will *also* switch to blockwise visual mode. You would have to cancel out of that after your search.

Comment: This is the command-line mapping for inserting characters literally into the command line, e.g. `^M` (enter) or `^[` (Esc). I don't think it will help to open search.

Comment: @minseong have you tried? Because I have and it does - at least in original Vim. Maybe the help section is off. But then `:help CTRL-V` is about visual mode, hmm.

Comment: I confirm that it works on both Vim and Neovim. It has one downside that it switch Vim and Neovim to Visual Block mode.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt you're right. And I hadn't even noticed. It's probably not what anybody would want (unless you want to search for the end of a visual block). I'll edit.